# Ask user for command including a filename confusion

Tags: java, arrays, reader

In this part of my program I ask the user for a command and a filename. The command can be 'read', 'content' or 'count'. In all the different tasks I need a file. I want the user to type in the console something like:

```
read Alice's Adventures In Wonderland.txt
```

For some reason I don't get how to implement this in 1 command. Now, I'm first asking the filename and afterwards I ask what to do with it. The following example is the 'read' command which asks for a file and counts all the words in the file:

```
case "read":
            int nrWords=countAllWords();
            System.out.println("The number of words in this file is: "+nrWords+"\n");
            break;
```

.

```
 private static int countAllWords() throws IOException
  {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter file name: ");
    String fileName=input.nextLine();

    FileInputStream inputStream=new FileInputStream(fileName);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line=bufferedReader.readLine();
    int nrWords=0;

    while(line!=null)
    {
      String[] wordsInLine=line.split(" ");
      nrWords=nrWords+wordsInLine.length;
      line=bufferedReader.readLine();
    }
    return nrWords;
  }
```

Can somebody explain how I can fit those 2 commands into one senctence in which my code understands what relates to what?

Comment: I think the Javascript tag should be replaced by a Java tag

Comment: Fixed the tag, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead what you can do here is to use the split function to break apart your command like so:

```
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
String command = line.split(" ")[0];
String fileName = line.substring(command.length);
```

And that way your fileName will be the rest of the String, and the command just the first element. `command` should be the command and `fileName` should be the file's name.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the entire command in one input, you can parse out the first word -- understanding that this is the 'action' -- and then the rest is the filename.

So first you'd get the entire command:

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter command: ");
String command = input.nextLine();
```

Then you'll want to parse out the action. It will always be the first word.

```
String action = command.substring(0, command.indexOf(' ')).trim();
String fileName = command.substring(command.indexOf(' ')).trim();
```

Now you can check what the action is and use the file as needed.

String's [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) method will return the index of the first occurrance of the specified character. So in this case we're using it to get the index of the first space. Note that `indexOf` will return -1 if the character is not present, so you'll want to trap appropriately for that. (Example scenario: user just enters "read" without a filename.)